# ValueError: expected an expression convertible to a polynomial in Polynomial ring

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy, symbolic-integration

I'm trying to write my mathcad model in python language, but I get some mistake.
The integration function should look like this:

[image: http://iscr.ru/photo/1471186985_snimok.PNG]

In python I wrote such code

```
from __future__ import division
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import math
from pylab import *

print(sp.__version__)

s  =  sp.Symbol('s')
x = sp.symbols('x')

t_start = 11
t_info = 1
t_transf = 2
t_stat_analyze = 3
t_repeat = 3.2
P = 0.1

def M1(s):
    return P/(t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 - (-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf)**2) + P/(        t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 - (-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)**2*(s + 1/t_transf)) + P/(t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 - (-P +         1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)**2*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + P/(t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 - (-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/        t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)**2*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf)) - P*(-(-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)**2) - (-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)**2*(s + 1/t_transf)))/(        t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 - (-P + 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))**2*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf))

def M2(s):
    return 2*P*((s + 1/t_transf)**(-2) + 1/((s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + (s + 1/t_stat_analyze)**(-2) + 1/((s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + 1/((s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)) + (s + 1/t_start)**(-2) + 1/((s + 1/        t_info)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + 1/((s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)) + 1/((s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)) + (s + 1/t_info)**(-2) - (P - 1)*((s + 1/t_transf)**(-2) + 1/((s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + (s + 1/t_repeat)**(-2))/(        t_repeat*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)) - (P - 1)*(1/(s + 1/t_transf) + 1/(s + 1/t_repeat))/(t_repeat*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/        t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)**2) - (P - 1)*(1/(s + 1/t_transf) + 1/(s + 1/t_repeat))/(t_repeat*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/        t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf)) - (P - 1)*(1/(s + 1/t_transf) + 1/(s + 1/t_repeat))/(t_repeat*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_transf)) - (P - 1)*(1/(        s + 1/t_transf) + 1/(s + 1/t_repeat))/(t_repeat*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)) + (P - 1)**2*(1/(s + 1/t_transf) + 1/(s + 1/t_repeat))**2/(        t_repeat**2*t_transf**2*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/t_transf)))**2*(s + 1/t_repeat)**2*(s + 1/t_transf)**2))/(t_info*t_start*t_stat_analyze*t_transf*(1 + (P - 1)/(t_repeat*t_transf*(s + 1/t_repeat)*(s + 1/        t_transf)))*(s + 1/t_info)*(s + 1/t_start)*(s + 1/t_stat_analyze)*(s + 1/t_transf))

T_realyze = M1(0)
D = M2(0)-M1(0)**2

alpha = T_realyze**2/D
myu = T_realyze/D

def F(t):
    if t<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return sp.integrate((myu**alpha)/(sp.gamma(alpha)*(x**(alpha-1))*sp.exp(myu*x)), (x, 0, t))

t=arange(0, 200, 1)
for i in t:
    print(F(i))
    i = i+1
```

So, when I'm trying to execute it, I had such error in

```
    return sp.integrate
```

function:

```
    $ python2.7 nta.py
    1.0
    ('T_realyze  =  ', 63.800000000000026)
    ('D  =  ', 2696.760000000001)
    ('alpha  =  ', 1.5093816283243602)
    ('myu  =  ', 0.02365801925273291)
    0
    ('myu*x  =  ', 0.0236580192527329*x)
    ('sp.exp(myu*x)', exp(0.0236580192527329*x))
    0
    1
    ('myu*x  =  ', 0.0236580192527329*x)
    ('sp.exp(myu*x)', exp(0.0236580192527329*x))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "nta.py", line 48, in <module>
        print(F(i))
      File "nta.py", line 43, in F
        return sp.integrate((myu**alpha)/(sp.gamma(alpha)*(x**(alpha-1))*sp.exp(myu*x)), (x, 0, t))
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1280, in integrate
        risch=risch, manual=manual)
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 486, in doit
        conds=conds)
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 887, in _eval_integral
        h = heurisch_wrapper(g, x, hints=[])
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/heurisch.py", line 130, in heurisch_wrapper
        unnecessary_permutations)
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/heurisch.py", line 657, in heurisch
        solution = _integrate('Q')
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/heurisch.py", line 646, in _integrate
        numer = ring.from_expr(raw_numer)
      File "/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/polys/rings.py", line 371, in from_expr
        raise ValueError("expected an expression convertible to a polynomial in %s, got %s" % (self, expr))
    ValueError: expected an expression convertible to a polynomial in Polynomial ring in _x0, _x1, _x2, _x3 over RR[_A0,_A1,_A2,_A3,_A4,_A5,_A6,_A7,_A8,_A9,_A10,_A11,_A12,_A13,_A14,_A15,_A16,_A17,_A18,_A19,_A20,_A21,_A22,_A23,_A24,_A25,_A26,_A27,_A28,_A29,_A30,_A31,_A32,_A33,_A34] with lex order, got 0.50938162832436*_x3**2.96316463805253*(_A0 + _A10*_x0*_x1 + 2*_A11*_x1*_x3 + _x0**2*_A12 + _A14*_x0*_x2 + _A2*_x0 + 2*_A20*_x0*_x3 + _A24*_x1*_x2 + _x2**2*_A27 + 2*_A28*_x3 + _x1**2*_A30 + 3*_x3**2*_A31 + 2*_A6*_x2*_x3 + _A8*_x2 + _A9*_x1) + 1.50938162832436*_x3**4.92632927610506*(_A10*_x1*_x3 + 2*_A12*_x0*_x3 + _A13*_x1*_x2 + _A14*_x2*_x3 + 2*_A15*_x0 + _A16*_x2 + _x2**2*_A18 + _A2*_x3 + _x3**2*_A20 + _A21 + _x1**2*_A3 + 2*_A33*_x0*_x2 + _A34*_x1 + 3*_x0**2*_A5 + 2*_A7*_x0*_x1) - _A10*_x0*_x3 - _x3**2*_A11 - _A13*_x0*_x2 - _x2**2*_A17 - 2*_A19*_x1*_x2 - _A22 - _A24*_x2*_x3 - 2*_A25*_x1 - 3*_x1**2*_A29 - 2*_A3*_x0*_x1 - 2*_A30*_x1*_x3 - _A34*_x0 - _A4*_x2 - _x0**2*_A7 - _A9*_x3 + _x2*_x3 + 0.0236580192527329*_x2*(_A13*_x0*_x1 + _A14*_x0*_x3 + _A16*_x0 + 2*_A17*_x1*_x2 + 2*_A18*_x0*_x2 + _x1**2*_A19 + 2*_A23*_x2 + _A24*_x1*_x3 + 3*_x2**2*_A26 + 2*_A27*_x2*_x3 + _A32 + _x0**2*_A33 + _A4*_x1 + _x3**2*_A6 + _A8*_x3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy appears to have difficulties evaluating the integral with floating point coefficients (in this case). However, it can find the integral in closed form when the constants of the integrand expression are symbolic.

```
a, b, c, t = sp.symbols('a,b,c,t', positive = True)
f = sp.Integral(a * sp.exp(-c*x)/(x**b),(x,0,t)).doit()
print f
```

Output:

```
-a*(-b*c**b*gamma(-b + 1)*lowergamma(-b + 1, 0)/(c*gamma(-b + 2)) + c**b*gamma(-b + 1)*lowergamma(-b + 1, 0)/(c*gamma(-b + 2))) + a*(-b*c**b*gamma(-b + 1)*lowergamma(-b + 1, c*t)/(c*gamma(-b + 2)) + c**b*gamma(-b + 1)*lowergamma(-b + 1, c*t)/(c*gamma(-b + 2)))
```

You can substitute the constants in this expression to get numerical results as follows (here, I use an example value of `t=4`):

```
f.subs({a:(myu**alpha)/sp.gamma(alpha), b:(alpha-1), c:myu, t:4}).n()
```

> ```
> 0.0154626407404632
> ```

Another option is to use `quad` from scipy (again using `t=4`):

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

quad(lambda x: (myu**alpha)/(sp.gamma(alpha)*(x**(alpha-1))*sp.exp(myu*x)), 0 ,4)[0]
```

> ```
> 0.015462640740458165
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll use the quad method because of its speed. Integral can be too slow in my project

Comment: @YuriKarabanov Note that the symbolic integral does not need to be computed every time you call your function. It can be computed once (off-line) and directly use the symbolic form in your function, where you only have to substitute the values of the coefficients. However, even with this approach, Scipy's quad may still be a faster approach.